# Change Bottom Navigation Icon colour (or) icon , on tap of bottom Item view in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview

The Question is regarding the Compose Bottom Navigation,

- I have created the bottom navigation view with NavHost
- I need to change the Icon state as (Enable/Disable) while clicking on it each time like changing the Icon or Icon colour itself

Comment: https://ashuflutterdev.medium.com/decoding-jetpack-compose-part-1-68aba0e26f8e

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you said you implement navigation already . so now you have to check **current route** and and bottom **navigation screen route**

```
val currentRoute = backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route; //check current route
        val selected = currentRoute == screens.route // if current route equal to screen route it return true
```

give icon color acc to selected route like this

```
  Icon(
                        imageVector = screens.icon,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        tint = if (selected) Color.White else Color.Black
                    )
```

here is full Bottom Navigation Bar implementation

```
@Composable

fun BottomBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    screens: List<ScreenModel.HomeScreens>,
    navController: NavController,

    ) {
    BottomNavigation {
        val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        screens.forEach {


                screens ->
            val currentRoute = backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route;
            val selected = currentRoute == screens.route

            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = screens.icon,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        tint = if (selected) Color.White else Color.Black
                    )
                },
                selected = selected,
                label = {
                    Text(
                        if (selected) screens.title else "", // Label
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                },

                onClick = {
                    if (currentRoute != screens.route) {
                        navController.navigate(screens.route)

                    }

                }

            )
        }

    }

}
```

screen model file

```
class ScreenModel {

    sealed class HomeScreens(
        val route: String,
        val title: String,
        val icon: ImageVector
    ) {
        object Home : HomeScreens("home", "Home", Icons.Filled.Home)
        object Search : HomeScreens("search", "Search", Icons.Filled.Search)
        object Profile : HomeScreens("profile", "MyNetwork", Icons.Filled.Person)

    }

    val screensInHomeFromBottomNav = listOf(
        HomeScreens.Home, HomeScreens.Search, HomeScreens.Profile
    )

}
```

Comment: the above code will navigate to the specific page if not the current route already selected , Is it possible to change the colour alone without navigating on tap of menu icon ? Kindly update if possible or not
My Use Case is : I have a mute Icon , on tap i need to perform Mute and UnMute Operation and also intimating the User by Navigation Icon  colour changes but not navigate must stay on the previous navigated page itself